# How to check if bluetooth packets are being recieved by BlueZ daemon

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I'm connecting to BLE devices on a Raspberry Pi (running Raspberry PI OS (bullseye)) running BlueZ 5.68. I call BlueZ's `AcquireNotify` method to read incoming packets. However I'm not receiving all the packets – when I run `btmon` I can see packets that `AcquireNotify` doesn't receive.

I'm trying to investigate where the packets are being dropped. I know they are being received over HCI but not at the application layer so I want to see if they are being received by the `bluetoothd` daemon. However `bluetoothd` doesn't include any packet information. I'm wondering what is the best way of checking if Bluetooth packets are being received by the BlueZ daemon?

Comment: Could it be that the kernel is following duplicates? https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/issues/235

Comment: @ukBaz Interesting, I looked through that and it seems it affects RSSI messages received while scanning. Do you know if it would also affect ACL Data packets?